# What does the presence of gravitational waves show?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, ligo

Is the essence of the [discovery of gravitational waves](http://www.ligo.caltech.edu/news/ligo20160211) that we now know that gravity propagates through space at the speed of light and not instantly?

Comment: BTW "gravity wave" described a fluid surface wave where the restoring force comes from gravity. What LIGO announced was the first observation of "gravitational waves". A detail that might have help your search.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean the direct detection of gravitational waves:

- it is another prediction of GR which has now been confirmed by experiment -- a test that GR has passed in other words;
- it is a direct detection of black holes interacting, which is, in fact, another test of GR it has passed;
- and finally it is an important step in a new kind of astronomy and an astonishing bit of engineering.

Although I am not an astrophysicist, I think that the masses of the two black holes were unusual, in terms of current models for their formation, so this particular event may also lead to changes in how we think about various astrophysical processes.

Comment: Do Gravitational waves by itself say something about existence of black holes and their interactions?

Comment: @NameYYY Well, yes insofar as black holes are a prediction of GR as well.  But this particular detection in particular really makes no sense unless the objects were black holes.